# Get Names ForEach Checked item in Checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach, while-loop, checkedlistbox

I want to get the names associated with the states i select in my program. Below is the code that i currently have. My database has multiple locations within a state that have different contacts. I just want to select a state and acquire everyone under that state. Thanks for the help!

```
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\\Database\\LocNo.accdb");
con.Open();

foreach (Object c in checkedListBox2.CheckedItems)
{
    if (checkedListBox2.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox2.Items.IndexOf(c)) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        str1 += c.ToString() + ","; 
        flag = 1;
    }
}

i = 0;
allSelectedtypestring = "";
allSelected = str1.Split(',');


while (allSelected.Length - 1 > i)
{
    str = "select c1 from table where state ='" + allSelected[i++] + "'";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    dr.Read();
    allSelectedtypestring += dr.GetString(11);
}

label30.Text = Convert.ToString(allSelectedtypestring);
con.Close();
```

Comment: What do you want to do if a user selects multiple items in the `CheckedListBox`? Do you want to return an aggregated list of all contacts that are assigned to the states or do you want to retrieve the contacts for one state after the other?

Comment: Good question, i want just an aggregate. Everyone in that state. Whichever is easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to retrieve the contacts:

```
var states = new List<string>();
foreach (Object c in checkedListBox2.CheckedItems)
{
    states.Add(c.ToString()); 
    flag = 1;  // Can also be substituted by states.Count > 0
}

using(var con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\\Database\\LocNo.accdb"))
{
    con.Open();
    using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        var paramIndex = 0;
        var paramClause = new System.Text.StringBuilder(100);
        foreach(var state in states)
        {
            if (paramClause.Length > 0)
                paramClause.Append(", ");
            paramClause.Append("?");
            var paramName = "State" + (paramIndex++).ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, state);
        }
        var paramsClause = string.Join(", ", cmd.Parameters.
        cmd.CommandText = "select distinct c1 from table where state IN (" + paramsClause.ToString() + ")";
        using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var contacts = new List<string>();
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                contacts.Add(rdr.GetString(0);
            }
            label30.Text = string.Join(", ", contacts);
        }
    }        
}
```

Please note that I've made the following changes:

- Added `using` statements to reliably dispose the connection, command and reader.
- Used a `List<string>` as a more convenient way to collect the selected states.
- Added DISTINCT to the SELECT in order to filter duplicate entries.
- Used a parameter in the command text in order to avoid SQL injection attacks. Though this way to use a parameter with an IN clause works for SQL Server, I haven't checked whether it also works for an Access database. Let me know in the comments if it doesn't work.

Comment: disregard, it was my error. This works perfectly! I'm going to test a few more things. Thank you!!

Comment: One last question, when i select more than 1 state the result is blank. ANy suggestions?

Comment: @hexc: might be that Access doesn't like the way I provided the parameter for IN. I've updated my post.